# How to replace one navigation controller with another one?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am new to IOS development and currently I am trying to make my own tab bar that connects to different navigation controllers.

I got it working with view controllers by follwoing this [tutorial](http://swiftiostutorials.com/tutorial-custom-tabbar-storyboard/). It basically creates a placeholder view and put views on it from different view controllers. However, I couldn't figure out how you can switch navigation controllers if my tab bar button connects to different navigation controllers.

Comment: A navigation controller is just a special kind of view controller. You need to give details of the code and explain what is going wrong

Comment: @Wain so basically the tutorial I linked takes view inside view controllers on a placeholder view.....but if I do it to a navigation controller, I would lose the navigation bar, and that's the problem I have